# In ASP.NET MVC, what's the best way to set a CSS Class for a <li>contained link-button from server side code?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way of mark the “current” navigation item in a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970660/best-way-of-mark-the-current-navigation-item-in-a-menu)

Right now we don't set any css class to our menu buttons, but we do when a button is hovered over via jQuery.  I'd like to set the css class **active** in server side code, so if the user navigates directly a different section, the appropriate menu button will already have it's proper css styles.  The only thing is that I'm not sure how to best do this in MVC.  The buttons are in a shared partial view like this (of course the functionality is not complete, but there should be enough for you to get the idea):

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <ul id="mainMenu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Accounts", "List", "Accounts", new { userId = 2 }, null)</li>
        <li><a href="?">Config</a></li>
        <li><a href="?">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

When a user clicks on the 'Accounts' button, I'd like to set a css class for the `<li>` element to be **active**.  Is the `AccountsController` the best (or only) place to do this?  Even for a shared partial view?

Here's the method being called when the user clicks on the Accounts link:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult List(Int64 userId)
{
    var serviceAccounts = _accountManager.GetAccounts(userId);
    var accounts = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ServiceModels.Account>, List<AccountModel>>(serviceAccounts);

    return View("List", accounts);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why do you want to set it on server side ?

Comment: the questions a bit unclear I had to read it multiple times, I think he wants to have the section you are in highlighted, similar how SO shows the Questions menu highlighted when viewing questions etc.

Comment: Exactly! I want to have the Accounts menu item highlighted when on the Accounts page, and the Config section highlighted when on the Config page, etc.  Now that the question was posed, I may not need to do it on the server side, but now i'm curious as to how.  I wanted to because if the user navigates to http://somesite.com/Accounts, then it would already be highlighted, no matter how they got there (i.e., they didn't have to actually click my Accounts button).

Comment: dupe -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043264/navigation-menu-with-highlight-in-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970660/best-way-of-mark-the-current-navigation-item-in-a-menu/8041629#8041629